# mini filter driver | passing information from pre-operation to post-operation

Tags: filter-driver

I'm tracking changed made to file and would like to "remember" and pass some information from the pre-operation callback to the post-operation callback.

What is the best way to do it?

[Edit: The driver should only support Windows 10 everything else is a bonus]

Comment: For what OS will you do your driver?

Comment: Edited the question for more info.

Comment: For Windows there is a WDK (Windows Drivers Development Kit), I'm not sure if it's available for free (a lot of MS products aren't). It contains also samples, including file system filter drivers, IMHO

Comment: See here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/minispy

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the **PVOID *CompletionContext** in PreOperation to store a pointer to the data you want to pass to the PostOperation.
In the PostOperation just use **CompletionContext** as it will be the data you pointed it to in the PreOperation.

For example:
PreOp:

```
MyPreOpData = ExAllocatePoolWithTag(DATA_SIZE);
FltGetFileNameInformation(&NameInfo);
MyPreData->NameInfo = NameInfo;
MyPreData->OtherData = MyDrvGetOtherData(Params);
*CompletionContext = MyPreData;
```

PostOp:

```
if (CompletionContext != NULL)
{
    PMY_DATA MyPreData = (PMY_DATA)CompletionContext;
    // now continue using the data queried in the PreOp
    ...
    // when done free it
    ExFreePoolWithTag(MyPreData);
}
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/fltkernel/nc-fltkernel-pflt_post_operation_callback) for more details.

Good luck,
Gabriel